# Unable to merge keras models after adding Lambda layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I have a list of 3 keras models that each have an output shape of `(None, 2)`. I also have a common keras base model that produces their input. My goal is to combine the 4 models but to only take the first output from each of the models in the list (so the final output should have shape `(None, 3)`. My problem occurs when I try to use a Lambda layer to extract the first output from each model.

If I omit the Lambda step and simply combine the models as follows, it creates a model that gives the correct output with shape `(None, 6)`:

```
>>> sequentials = [Sequential([base_model, m]) for m in models]
>>> output = merge([s.output for s in sequentials], mode='concat')
>>> combined = Model(input=base_model.layers[0].input, output=output)
>>> combined.predict(X)
array([[  8.52127552e-01,   1.47872433e-01,   1.89960217e-13,
          1.00000000e+00,   7.56258190e-01,   2.43741751e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

The problem occurs when I first use a Lambda layer to extract the first value from each model:

```
>>> print([m.output_shape for m in models])
[(None, 2), (None, 2), (None, 2)]
>>> for m in models:
        m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[0], output_shape=(1,)))
>>> print([m.output_shape for m in models])
[(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]
>>> sequentials = [Sequential([base_model, m]) for m in models]
>>> print([s.output_shape for s in sequentials])
[(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]
>>> output = merge([s.output for s in sequentials],
                   output_shape=(len(sequentials),), mode='concat')
>>> combined = Model(base_model.layers[0].input, output=output)
>>> print(combined.output_shape)
(None, 3)
>>> combined.predict(X)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4f4ed3bd605d> in <module>()
----> 1 ann.combined.predict(X)

./.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
   1217         f = self.predict_function
   1218         return self._predict_loop(f, ins,
-> 1219                                   batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   1220
   1221     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

./.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose)
    904
    905             for i, batch_out in enumerate(batch_outs):
--> 906                 outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
    907             if verbose == 1:
    908                 progbar.update(batch_end)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)
```

What is the right way to merge these models while only taking the single output value from each one?

Note that I can successfully use a Lambda function if I apply it *after* merging the models as follows:

```
>>> sequentials = [Sequential([base_model, m]) for m in models]
>>> output = merge([s.output for s in sequentials], mode='concat')
>>> filtered = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,::2], lambda s: (s[-1] / 2,))(output)
>>> combined = Model(input=base_model.layers[0].input, output=filtered)
>>> combined.predict(X)
array([[  1.89960217e-13,   7.56258249e-01,   8.52127552e-01]], type=float32)
```

But I would like to know how to apply it *before* the merge.

Comment: do you compile the models at some point? not sure if it will change anything but it's just an idea

Comment: No, the models are all loaded from files (they were compiled & trained before saving).

Comment: Try `m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0], output_shape=(1,)))`

Comment: @MarcinMożejko You were close. That changes the error to `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (1)`. It runs successfully if I use `lambda x: x[:,:1]`. Since you got me going in the right direction, feel free to post as an answer (preferably with explanation) and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: Ah right. I think that `m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,[0]], output_shape=(1,)))` should also work correct.

Comment: It did not like [0]: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

Comment: Interesting - I would check that. `m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0], output_shape=(1,)))` Changes the dimensionality of a `tensor` and this causes an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lied with a little inconsistency in `Lambda` slicing. Although the `shape` of output doesn't take into account the `batch` dimension - one should remember that `tensor` provided to `Lambda` layers also have this additional dimension. This is why the following line causes an error:

```
m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[0], output_shape=(1,)))
```

This should be changed to:

```
m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:1], output_shape=(1,)))
```

Beware of the following way of slicing:

`m.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0], output_shape=(1,)))`

as it changes dimensionality of a `tensor`.